# Aggregate and count an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and i want to aggregate each word in it and count them, like so:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Notice
        [1] => co
        [2] => co
        [3] => Notice
        [4] => co
        [5] => co
        [6] => sls
    )
```

should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [Notice] => 2
    [co] => 4
    [sls] => 1
)
```

what is a ggod way to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at [**`array_count_values()`**](http://www.php.net/function.array-count-values)

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$array = array("Notice", "co", "co", "Notice", "co", "co", "sls");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [Notice] => 2
    [co] => 4
    [sls] => 1
)
```

For more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: now its call spoon feeding.